# Parse Json Error Logstash

Tags: logstash

I am trying to read logs inform of json and spitting the result to stdout with logstash my json file is as follows:

I wonder how would I parse below json

```
{"shoppers" : [
{
"type": "login",
"source": "user",
"triggered_at": "Login Screen",
"triggered_by": "Login Button",
"api_url": "<URL>",
"username": "Shopper123",
"timestamp": "17.04.2017 13:37:57"
},
{
"type": "logout",
"source": "user",
"triggered_at": "Account Screen",
"triggered_by": "User Pressed Logout Button",
"api_url": "<URL>",
"username": "Shopper123",
"timestamp": "17.04.2017 13:37:57"
}
]}
```

my logstash conf sample file shown below:
As you can see I am reading from s3 bucket and I am using json filter but the result is always showing me _parsejsonerror

```
input {
    s3 {
        access_key_id => '<access_key>'
        secret_access_key => '<secret_key>'
        bucket => 'some-bucket'
        region => 'eu-west-2'
        type => 'shopper_app'
        delete => true
        sincedb_path => "/home/user/logstash/last-s3-file"
        codec => json_lines
    }
}


filter {

    json {
        source => "message"
        add_field => ["type", "%{[message][type]}"]
    }
}



output
{
    stdout {codec => rubydebug}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved the problem the issue was due to malformed json file. The json file should not contain new lines it should be as follows:

```
[{"type": "login","source": "user","triggered_at": "Login Screen","triggered_by": "Login Button","api_url": "<URL>","username": "Shopper123","timestamp": "17.04.2017 13:37:57"},{"type": "logout","source": "user","triggered_at": "Account Screen","triggered_by": "User Pressed Logout Button","api_url": "<URL>","username": "Shopper123","timestamp": "17.04.2017 13:37:57"}]
```

Thanks